# error installing steam on ubuntu 14.04 fatal error loading steamui.so

Tags: steam, 32-bit

When I try to install steam it crashes and provides an error message that says:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
>   libGL.so.1

and after i press ok steam says:

> fatal error:failes to load steamui.so

I am running 64 Ubuntu GNOME. I have tried looking for other answers online but they all seem out of date and no longer apply.

EDIT:
when fix attempted (`apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`) it says:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem yesterday then I reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 and I deleted all files and operating system.I installed Steam Launcher on Ubuntu Software center.Then I wrote `apt-get install steam` [This process need to open root] Then steam installed update itself.Then steam opened successfully.

Comment: using `sudo su` then `apt-get install steam` was all I need to do to get it all working...

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit `libGL.so.1` is provided by package `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) then run the following to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Comment: just did that now came up with the message:Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: @lukewhittington edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: done uploading the changes thanks for trying to help btw

Comment: @lukewhittington Try running: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get -f install`, then `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing the problem above and the method suggested doesn't work, please try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size. After looking at the `LD_DEBUG=libs` dump of the client, I found that `steamui.so` was looking for `libGL.so.1`

Which means you have to find where it is, because it's not in any directory listed in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` enviroment variable.

So, at a terminal, try:

```
sudo find / -name libGL.so.1
```

This will list out where all of them are... and if you're using Optimus and/or 64-bit, it'll be in several places.

What I did is created a "bin" directory, where I created a shell script called "steam.sh". Inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/bin/steam $*
```

(Three lines. BTW, I'm running 64-bit and Bumblebee to boot, so later on I'll stick an optirun statement in here).

This fixed things up for me. Later on I'll expand this script out so I can say Intel only or Nvidia only.